# Date lookup issue: Unable to get VLookup property of WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, date, runtime-error, vlookup

I've tried almost everything in most of the other similar type questions but I can't seem to solve the runtime error. Help please!

What I want to achieve: 
1) My macro is supposed to get date from report summary files that are created every day hence, it requires the user to input which date of report he wants the data from
2) I use the vlookup method to get the data from the relevant row and input it into the central workbook with the macro
3) Every part of the code works except using the date to Vlookup and it will give me this error message
4) I have tested the code using other text based lookup values and the whole macro works (i.e. i looked up the row which has the "Total" value so it looks up "Total" but i require the macro to look up the rows with the date as the look up value)

Addtional Info:
1) In the lookup file, the dates are in the format of "m/d/yyyy" but presented in the format of "dd-mmm-yy" (but i've tried both and they dont work)

```
Sub GetData()

Dim strDate As Date
  strDate = InputBox("Input date of report to retrieve        (Format: DD-MM-YYYY)", "Input Date", Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY"))
  If IsDate(strDate) Then


'there is some code here not relevant but basically i need to keep manipulating the date throughout the code


With ActiveSheet
    Dim XstrDate
    Dim Xfile As String

    XstrDate = Format(strDate, "mmm DD, YYYY")
    Xfile = "C:\...\...\...\Report " & XstrDate & ".xls"


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim returnValue as Variant

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Xfile)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:K")


Dim Xdate As String
    Xdate = Format(XstrDate, "m/d/yyyy")

returnValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Xdate, rng, 2, 0)

'... more code
```

remember, i've tried looking up using the text in the same column and it returned me a value. So i suspect the problem lies with the date format or something

Any smart and kind soul want to offer some suggestions here:)

Comment: This error can occur if the value you're looking for is not found. I'm assuming the date you're trying to match to Xdate is in column A, if it's not then VLookup will not find it as it only searches the leftmost column of the specified range, returning the value in the nth column of that range as specified in argument 3. If this isn't the source of the problem then you probably want to check your date formats as Excel stores dates by their serial number so they probably won't match a string.

Comment: @Aiken yes the dates are in column A! Like i said, i tested the code with other text values in column A (eg the last row which has the value of "Total") and the code was able to return me a value. So like you say, i suspect it may be a date format error but i've tried all sorts of possible date format but it still failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a different approach and found another solution to this problem. 
Rather than use Vlookup, this is the other method that bypass the problem of VLookup date format problem, (having defined vdate in previous statements)

```
Dim rnge As Range, i As Long
Sheets("Summary").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set rnge = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
If rnge Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Date Not Found"
     GoTo done
End If


For i = rnge.Count To 1 Step -1
If rnge.Cells(i).Value = vdate Then rnge.Cells(i).EntireRow.Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AnotherSheet").Range("A1")
Next

done:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel internally stores dates as a Serial Number (e.g. 1/1/2014 = 41640), which you can observe yourself if you enter a date into a cell and then change the format to Number.

With this in mind it's unlikely that a VBA date and an Excel date can be matched using the VLookup function so in my experience the best solution is to convert your date into its serial number and then perform the VLookup on that value instead.

```
Dim Ndate As Long
Dim returnValue As Date

Ndate = DateSerial(<Year>, <Month>, <Day>)
returnValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Ndate, <rng>, <col>, False)
```

If you need to construct your `DateSerial(...)` function from a `Date` variable in VBA you can use the `Year(<date>)`, `Month(<date>)`, and `Day(<date>)` functions to break it down into the required components.

*Note: I've tried this example in the format* `.VLookup(DateSerial(2014,1,1),...)` *and it still causes the same error, hence storing the return value of DateSerial in a numeric variable first.*

Happy Coding!